# How to get UIRL of windows 10

Tags: azure, microsoft365, azure-purview

As shown in the image below, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/double-key-encryption?view=o365-worldwide#to-configure-tenant-and-key-settings-for-dke) article, from Microsoft, asks about entering the hostname of a machine on which a utility was installed. And it gives the example of a hostname as `https://dkeservice.contoso.com`. I am installing the utility in `Windows 10` that is a part of [Microsoft 365 Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/networking-roadmap-microsoft-365?view=o365-worldwide). **Question**: In my scenario, what will be the url for Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you linked to

> Locate the JwtAudience. Replace  with the hostname of the machine where the DKE service will run. For example: "https://dkeservice.contoso.com"

To get the appropriate hostname open up a command prompt under the Windows 10 machine the DKE service is running on and type "hostname".  This will give you the hostname of the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: The command prompt>hosthame just gives my computer name, say, myComputer. But the article is asking for entering in a url form, for example: `https://dkeservice.contoso.com`. So, I'm not sure what url I need to enter that represent my computer name.

Comment: What is your domain name?  The FQDN will be that hostname, plus your domain name.  For example, if your domain is “mydomain.com” you’ll use “https://mycomputer.my domain.com” as the JwtAudience value.